# GCP auto scaler : How to configure auto scaler to scale up only if CPU usage has crossed 70% for more than 5 minutes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I have a managed instance group with an HTTP(S) LB in front of it.
Currently, I have set up an auto-scaler policy to scale up or down based on CPU utilization and the threshold is set to 70%.
But I have observed that if there is any momentary spike in CPU usage for just a short while, new instances get added and immediately after a few minutes, some of the existing instances get deleted since the CPU usage would have come down.
I want the auto-scaler to ignore any momentary spikes by saying add more instances only if the CPU usage goes above 70% for more than 5 minutes.
How do I achieve this?

Regards,
Shobhana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.150791921.-632935758.1538146756#policies) dynamically creates or deletes VMs to meet the group target, not as per individual instance. These target are based on group overall utilization.

> If you scale based on CPU utilization, you can set your target utilization level at 75% and the autoscaler will maintain the CPU utilization of the specified group of instances at or close to 75%.

**For example**

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-autoscaling example-managed-instance-group 
--max-num-replicas 20 --target-cpu-utilization 0.75 --cool-down-period 90`

Test: During periods of heavy CPU utilization, if utilization reaches close to 100%, the autoscaler estimates that the Group may already be heavily overloaded. In these cases, the autoscaler increases the number of instance by at least an extra 50% or a minimum of 4 instances, whichever is higher. There's no option currently available to specify the time interval for sequential monitoring of total utilization before scaling up or down.

You may report this as a feature request with [Issue Trackers.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=0)